# How apply flexbox in a nested list (HTML-CSS only)

Tags: html, css, list, flexbox, nested

So I have homework to do and I have blocked it since yesterday on it, I try several things and I do some research but I still figure it out.

**This is what I have a problem with, the orange rectangle on the capture below:**
**I can't position the items of the Burger order as in the image, I have to use flexbox or grid ....**

[image]

**Here are the instructions to follow:**
The order items must be integrated into a list at two levels: the items
Burgers and Donuts on the first level and items ordered on the 2nd level.

```css
.grid-commande {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 2fr, 1fr);
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.flex-commande {
  display: flex;
  width: 66%;
}

.flex-commande ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-fleche {
  list-style-image: url("../img/icon-fleche.png");
}

.commande-detail {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: #6cb9e2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-detail {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <h1>Ma Commande</h1>

  <div class=" grid-commande">
    <div class="flex-commande">
      <ul>
        <li class="icon-fleche">
          <h2>Burgers</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ Quantité: 1</li>
            <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ Quantité: 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="icon-fleche">
          <h2>Beignes</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ Quantité: 1</li>
            <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ Quantité: 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="commande-detail ">
      <h2>Détails</h2>
      <div class=flex-detail>
        <div>
          <p><strong>Sous-total:</strong></p>
          <p><strong>Taxes:</strong></p>
          <p><strong>Total:</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>29.96$</p>
          <p>4.49$</p>
          <p>34.45$</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="principalBTN">Commander</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made

```css
.grid-commande {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.flex-commande {
width: 70%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
margin: 0px;
padding: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.icon-fleche { 
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
margin: 0px;
}
.icon-fleche h2 {
list-style-image: url("../img/icon-fleche.png");
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 10px;
}
.icon-fleche > ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0px 0px 30px;
padding: 0px;
}
.icon-fleche > ul > li
{
padding: 15px 0px;
margin: 0px;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.each-title
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-title ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.left-title ul li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-right: 15px;
}
.left-title ul li+li::before
{
content: '|';
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: -12px;
top: -1px;
}
.commande-detail {
width:30%;
background-color: #6cb9e2;
padding: 10px;
}
.flex-detail {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<main class="container">
        <h1>Ma Commande</h1>
        <div class=" grid-commande">
            <div class="flex-commande">

                <div class="icon-fleche">
                    <h2>Burgers</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="each-title">
                                <div class="left-title">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Le commodo</li>
                                        <li>9.99$</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right-title">
                                    Quantité: 1
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="each-title">
                                <div class="left-title">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Le commodo</li>
                                        <li>9.99$</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right-title">
                                    Quantité: 1
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-fleche">
                    <h2>Beignes</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="each-title">
                                <div class="left-title">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Le commodo</li>
                                        <li>9.99$</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right-title">
                                    Quantité: 1
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="each-title">
                                <div class="left-title">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Le commodo</li>
                                        <li>9.99$</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right-title">
                                    Quantité: 1
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- <ul>
                    <li class="icon-fleche">
                        <h2>Burgers</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ Quantité: 1</li>
                            <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ Quantité: 1</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="icon-fleche">
                        <h2>Beignes</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ Quantité: 1</li>
                            <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ Quantité: 1</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul> -->

            </div>
            <div class="commande-detail ">
                <h2>Détails</h2>
                <div class=flex-detail>
                    <div>
                        <p><strong>Sous-total:</strong></p>
                        <p><strong>Taxes:</strong></p>
                        <p><strong>Total:</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>29.96$</p>
                        <p>4.49$</p>
                        <p>34.45$</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="principalBTN">Commander</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
```

my own css for you. You can check my css and also html.

Answer (score 0):

The desired solution was unclear. This answer is based on the image you provided using the requirement `flex`. You can see all changes I made in the CSS under `/* added CSS */`.

```css
.flex-commande {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-commande ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-fleche {
  list-style-image: url("../img/icon-fleche.png");
}

.commande-detail {
  background-color: #6cb9e2;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.flex-detail {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* added CSS */

.orange {
  border: solid 2px orange;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

.wrapper > ul:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
}

.orange > li {  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dotted {
  border: dotted 2px black;
}

.dotted > li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.icon-fleche > h2 {
  margin: .3em;
}

ul {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <h1>Ma Commande</h1>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="icon-fleche">
        <h2>Burgers</h2>
        <ul class="orange">
          <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ <span>Quantité: 1</span></li>
          <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ <span>Quantité: 1</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="icon-fleche">
        <h2>Beignes</h2>
        <ul class="dotted">
          <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ <span>Quantité: 1</span></li>
          <li>Le commodo | 9.99$ <span>Quantité: 1</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="commande-detail ">
      <h2>Détails</h2>
      <div class=flex-detail>
        <div>
          <p><strong>Sous-total:</strong></p>
          <p><strong>Taxes:</strong></p>
          <p><strong>Total:</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>29.96$</p>
          <p>4.49$</p>
          <p>34.45$</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="principalBTN">Commander</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```